# NSOpenPanel choose a directory ( not a file)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to let user to choose a directory for saving a file. but how to make sure the url is a directory not a file?

```
NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setCanCreateDirectories:YES];

[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSArray* urls = [panel URLs];
        for (NSURL *url in urls) {
            //here how to judge the url is a directory or a file
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// First, check if the URL is a file URL, as opposed to a web address, etc.
if (url.isFileURL) {
  BOOL isDir = NO;
  // Verify that the file exists 
  // and is indeed a directory (isDirectory is an out parameter)
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: url.path isDirectory: &isDir]
      && isDir) {
    // Here you can be certain the url exists and is a directory
  }
}
```

Comment: See below for the correct answer, from Kendrick Ledet; that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28):

Update for anyone reading this in the future:

In Swift, checking if the picked path is a file can be avoided by using

```
panel.canChooseFiles = false
```

Comment: Technically that works for Objective-C too, although I'd use `NO` instead of `false`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but in Swift you should use false.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** version:

```
if (url.isFileURL) {
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false
    if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: &isDir)) { 
       if isDir.boolValue {
                            print("It's a Directory path")
                          } else {
                            print("It's a file path")
                        }
                    }
}
```